# ActiveRecord, many to many two-way relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a question and i hope someone can explain this to me. Example  relationship:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :issues
  has_many :tasks, through: :issues
end

class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :task
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :issues
  has_many :users, through: :issues
end
```

I will try to create some models through association:

```
user = User.create
task = user.tasks.new 
user.tasks # [#<Task id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]
task.users # []
```

Question 1. Is this intended to be one way association or am I doing something wrong?

```
user.tasks.new.save     
 SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("created_at", "updated_at") ...

user.tasks.create    
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "tasks" ("created_at", "updated_at") ..
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "issues" ("created_at", "task_id", "updated_at", "user_id") ...
```

Question 2: Why only create method adds record to join table?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating many to many association between user and task. In order to have one way association you need to write

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :tasks
 end

 class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
 end
```

This will create one to many association between user and task.

And

create method of Active Record updates the database but new method only create model object as you can see with the log.

you need to call save after new

```
task = user.tasks.new 
user.save
```

this will actually save the user along with task

This link will explain you more on associations

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html